# eloquent use ->with() with only retrieving one column?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

e.g.

i want to retrieve all users with the relation roles, but only the field of role name.

something like this:

`User::with('user_role', 'user_role.name')`

does something like this exist? i have looked around and don't seem to find something related. The performance might be better if you can filter down the returned columns

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use something like this:

```
$user = User::with('user_role:foreign_key,name')->find(1);
```

In this case, the `foreign_key` should be the name of the foreign key that is used to build the relation and it's required here and then you may pass other field names to select them by separating with comma.

This is not documented so be careful, it could be removed in the newer versions. It exists there and below is the code sample, taken from `Laravel-5.3` (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), it works tho (This is how I've used it: `User::with('messages:recipient_id,body')->get()`):

```
/**
 * Parse a list of relations into individuals.
 *
 * @param  array  $relations
 * @return array
 */
protected function parseWithRelations(array $relations)
{
    $results = [];

    foreach ($relations as $name => $constraints) {
        // If the "relation" value is actually a numeric key, we can assume that no
        // constraints have been specified for the eager load and we'll just put
        // an empty Closure with the loader so that we can treat all the same.
        if (is_numeric($name)) {
            if (Str::contains($constraints, ':')) {
                list($constraints, $columns) = explode(':', $constraints);

                $f = function ($q) use ($columns) {
                    $q->select(explode(',', $columns));
                };
            } else {
                $f = function () {
                    //
                };
            }

            list($name, $constraints) = [$constraints, $f];
        }

        // We need to separate out any nested includes. Which allows the developers
        // to load deep relationships using "dots" without stating each level of
        // the relationship with its own key in the array of eager load names.
        $results = $this->parseNestedWith($name, $results);

        $results[$name] = $constraints;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add constraints to eager loaded relations by supplying a `with` array with closure as the value with the relation as the key.

```
$user = User::with(['user_role' => function($query) {
    return $query->select('name');
}]);
```

Comment: this should probably be accepted but i cannot test so i am sorry.